# Sallen-Key filter with input signal attenuation

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider, low-pass, sallen-key, attenuation

I want to reduce input signal amplitude before it gets to the low pass filter by 6dB. I could use MFB topology for K<1, but that would invert the phase. Is there a solution that keeps the phase? Also if I choose to use MFB, how does that type of attenuation compare to using passive components only to reduce amplitude SNR and distortion wise?

Comment: If 2nd order, what kind of ***shape*** do you want with the filter? Passive components don't provide any choice here. Active filters do provide a range of choices (which also impact group delay, etc.) So I think you need to write a lot more about what you are wanting to achieve. Just my thought, anyway.

Comment: I am applying a LPF to a voltage output DAC. The default output level is too high for the rest of the circuit, so I need to reduce the amplitude either before the filter or after the filter. Since the supply voltage for the op amp is not very high (it can be as low as ±2.5V), using lower input levels is preferable to reduce signal distortion. If I just put a voltage divider after the DAC, then the filter operates with high voltage swing which I do not want.

Comment: The shape is 2nd order Butterworth or Bessel.

Comment: So \$\zeta=\frac12\sqrt{2}\$ \$\left(Q=\sqrt{2}\right)\$ or \$\zeta=\frac12\sqrt{3}\$ \$\left(Q=\frac23\sqrt{3}\right)\$, then. Sallen & Key provide in their TR-50 paper (1954, MIT Lincoln Lab) cases where K<1, specifically. Have you looked over their work, already?

Comment: In case it helps, here's a link to their [later 1955 paper](https://www.tinaja.com/third/sallen_key.pdf). It's not as complete as the TR-50 paper from 1954. But it's good.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I browsed through the paper and drafted a topology with two additional resistors, one in the feedback loop and another from the positive input to ground. I did not encounter this exact topology in the paper, but somehow it works in the simulation. By changing the value of these resistors I can adjust attenuation. I still need to figure out how this is different from using a voltage divider on the input.